# Installing puppet 3.7 from the raspbian repositories

Tags: raspbian, puppet

I am currently running puppet 2.7 on my Pi, but that's a bit behind the times.

The currently suggested approach for upgrading Puppet is to use the puppet labs repo ( see [Puppet on Raspberry Pi](http://stdout.no/puppet-on-raspberry-pi/) or [Installing Puppet 3 in a BeagleBone or Raspberry Pi](http://blog.csanchez.org/2014/01/23/installing-puppet-3-in-a-beaglebone-or-raspberry-pi/)). However, I see that the main repo has puppet 3.7., e.g. http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/p/puppet/ contains both puppet-common_2.7.23-1~deb7u3_all.deb and puppet-common_3.7.2-4_all.deb .

I ran an apt-get update/dist-upgrade today, but I still don't get the updated puppet. apt-cache does not recognize the new version:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg puppet
Package: puppet
Versions: 
2.7.23-1~deb7u3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages
                  MD5: 1dc71ec043c0ade030b8a9e18410f9ef
```

How can I install the updated puppet packages from the raspbian repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* I know what is going on. I am currently running the wheezy-based version of raspbian. [Wheezy contains Puppet 2.7](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/puppet), while [Jessie contains Puppet 3.7](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/puppet).

So the only solution would be to upgrade to raspbian jessie.